# Powershell: Check csv file values against every line in another csv file

Tags: csv, powershell, scripting

I have 2 .csv files.

Examples:

1.csv:

```
Users
userA
userB
```

2.csv:

```
groupid,user,random
1,userA,randomtext1
2,userA,randomtest2
3,userA,randomtext3
3,userB,randomtext1
5,userB,randomtext2
6,userB,randomtext2
```

I want to take the value of the one column in 1.csv and check it against a column in 2.csv.

Basically what output I would like is:

```
UserA is a member of 1
UserA is a member of 2
UserA is a member of 3
UserB is a member of 3
UserB is a member of 4
UserB is a member of 5
UserB is a member of 6
```

I know I can use `Import-Csv` but I just can't get around how to do this?

I have tried to put 1.csv into an array but how can i then check the array against every line in 2.csv to check if the user is on a given line and then take the groupip?

```
$user = @()
$users = Import-Csv 1.csv | Foreach {$user += $_.Users}
```

I have tried a lot of different things and i cant get it to work.

Any tips appreciated.

/Rasmus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the usernames you're interested in into an array, use `Where-Object` to filter on rows that match those user names:

```
# Read user names into string array
$TargetUsers = Import-Csv .\1.csv |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Users

# Now import and filter the CSV with the relationships
Import-Csv .\2.csv |Where-Object {$TargetUsers -contain $_.user} |ForEach-Object {
    # Output the string with the information you need
    "$($_.user) is a member of $($_.groupid)"
} |Out-File .\output.txt
```